# Error 500 while exporting Jupyter notebooks

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, julia, jupyter, ijulia-notebook

I've set the Julia kernel in the Jupyter notebook.

I wrote a notebook, but when I try to export it I get the following error:
[image]
Which reads:

```
nbconvert failed: No module named 'pygments.lexers.julia'
```

I don't really know what is the error or how to solve it, but it shows up whenever I try to export to pdf or HTML.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure the environment that has Jupyter installed also has `pygments` v1.6 or later installed.

Comment: how do i do that